# Read a list which has been saved as .txt in R

Tags: r, list, import

Hi create a list file in R and then I saved it using `write.table()` to file.txt.

Now, I would like to import the file.txt in R but I have problems doing that.

The list in the file.txt is like this (opening it with Notes of Windows).

```
"1" c(133, 292, 460, 603, 762, 929, 1027, 1060, 1199, 1373, 1523, 1698, 1875)
"2" c(145, 322, 475, 654, 790, 922, 1085, 1251, 1411, 1451, 1562, 1737, 1861)
"3" c(142, 308, 370, 473, 612, 765, 920, 1096, 1225, 1374, 1501, 1640, 1771, 1878)
"4" c(146, 324, 389, 464, 611, 748, 914, 1048, 1203, 1338, 1499, 1672, 1823)
"5" c(146, 287, 329, 482, 659, 815, 843, 980, 1157, 1315, 1450, 1585, 1756, 1866, 1898)
"6" c(133, 259, 443, 590, 772, 917, 996, 1059, 1081, 1206, 1365, 1523, 1690, 1845)
```

I have tried to use `read.table()` but it replies with an Error.

How can I import the file and read all the lines?

Comment: Saving using an R format such as .RData or rds might work better for you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to parse this into a list of integers. You would benefit in the future by using `save` and `load` in the future.

```
# read in file 
myList <- gsub("(^.*\\ c\\(|\\)$)", "", readLines("<path>/<fileName>"))
# get integer list
myList <- lapply(strsplit(myList, split=", "), as.integer)
```

The `readLines` function reads in each line as a string and returns a character vector and `gsub` strips out "c(" and ")". This is then fed to `strsplit` which splits on the " ," and returns a list of character vectors which is fed to `lapply` which converts these vectors into integers with `as.integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combination of `parse`,`eval` and `cbind`:

```
text_data <- readLines(file("file.txt"))

theoutput <- do.call(cbind,lapply(gsub(".*(?=c)","",text_data,perl = T), function(x) {
    eval(parse(text=x))
}))
```